# How do I prepare for the skill test based on this job role?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-modeling, math-software, career-development

[image]

This was a Scientist job advertisement of famous space research Institution. Third column describes the job responsibility. They may conduct skill test. How do a person develop these skills? Can you suggest How does a person prepare for this skill test? Please suggest textbooks.

Comment: *Please suggest textbooks.* --- Why would you think there would be textbooks devoted to specific job skills tests? For one thing, the market for something like this (2 or 3 dozen people over a few years?) would be so small that it wouldn't be remotely profitable to do this. And who would write the textbook(s)? Certainly not the present employees, as this would undermine their job search tasks, and they besides they wouldn't have time for something like this. Certainly not non-employees, as presumably they would not have access to secure job skills test documents.

Comment: How do I develop a basic mathematical modelling skill in MATLAB?

Comment: I guess take a course in it or study it using library books and/or purchased books and/or online resources. This is not something I know anything about, despite having  a Ph.D. in mathematics (and a fair number of applied courses, although mostly in classical applied mathematical topics such as Fourier series, ordinary and partial differential equations, etc.), and thus this is not a job I would be qualified for. For the same reason, you might not be qualified for it, although with additional learning (somehow) you might become qualified. **(continued)**

Comment: A friend of mine recently spent a little over 1.5 years transitioning from a background in physics and philosophy to data science, mostly by self-study and posting his work on GitHub. It took him 1.5 years (lots and lots of self-study involved), and many dozens of job applications (and several interviews) before he was hired, this being by a company that was mainly looking for someone not too much of an expert (non-expert means non-expensive salary) and that was looking for someone who gave evidence of being able to learn on the job. He also had to move over 350 km away for the job.